# webservice can't get gzipped request data

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, gzip, content-type

I'm trying to decode a GZipped request which is sent to the webservice with Content-Type: application/x-gzip.

I've implemented an HttpHandler which adds a GZip decompression filter and it appears to be working. Here's the code:

```
    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
        HttpContext ctx = app.Context;

        if (!ctx.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToLower().Contains(".asmx"))
            return;

        // test
        if ("gzip" == ctx.Request.Headers["Content-encoding"])
        {
            app.Request.Filter = new GZipStream(app.Request.Filter,
               CompressionMode.Decompress);
        }

        if (IsEncodingAccepted("gzip"))
        {

            app.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(app.Response.Filter,
      CompressionMode.Compress);
            SetEncoding("gzip");
        }
        else if (IsEncodingAccepted("deflate"))
        {
            app.Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(app.Response.Filter,
      CompressionMode.Compress);
            SetEncoding("deflate");
        }
    }
    private bool IsEncodingAccepted(string encoding)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Accept-encoding"] != null &&
          HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Accept-encoding"].Contains(encoding);
    }
    private void SetEncoding(string encoding)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", encoding);
    }
```

Unfortunately, i keep getting this error all the time:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: Content Type application/x-gzip was not supported by service https://127.0.0.1/ModuloWS.asmx.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.
```

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I've been busting my nuts over this the entire day.

P.S. The request is being GZip encoded using a GZipMessageEncoder which was taken out of the WCF sample projects on the MSDN website.

Answer (score 1):

This error is well ahead of your code. It's bouncing at the WCF framework level, saying that your service is not configured to accept content type "application/x-gzip". To remedy this, configure your WCF to permit said content type. The information on how to do so is scattered throughout the net, but [this is a good start](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d67d8ef9-b407-4622-bcde-344880b55ec1/help-needed-gzip-encoding-problem-with-wcf-service). Where ever you got the sample code from at MSDN may also have sample config that enables gzip.

Comment: The problem i think is that the service is a regular .NET web service but the client is a WCF client. I need to find a way to configure this on the server side (the regular WebService)... Go an idea?